# How to get one random object from multiple arrays with percent chance in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have 3 arrays of objects:

```
const fruits = [
{name: "Banana"}, 
{name: "Apple"}, 
{name: "Peach"}
]

const car = [
{name: "Audi"}, 
{name: "Bentley"}
]

const books = [
{name: "Alice in wonderland"}, 
{name: "Deep in the dark"}, 
{name: "Hunting Show"}
]
```

one temporary array where I will store random objects from arrays

```
const tempArray = []
```

I want to get random object from random array

80% percentage chance that I get random object from fruits or car array

20% percentage chance that I get random object from books array

Example: Random chance is 80% -> random object from array fruits is pushed to tempArray and
tempArray should have object with bane "Banana"

Random chance is 20% -> Random object from array books is pushed to tempArray and tempArray should have object with name "Hunting Show"

**How can I do it in javascript?**

Comment: Very likely [some of these will work](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+weighted+random+from+arrays+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `const chance = Math.random()`  will give you a number from 0 (inclusive) to 1, from that you can check if `chance > 0.2` then push `car` or `fruit` to the temp array else push `books` to the temp array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to get two random numbers - the first to decide which group to pick and the second to pick that an item from that.  To give one group a higher chance of being picked, the first random number needs to be from a range 1-100 (to allow for percentages) and the group is then determined by a range within that.

For example, to give the fruits group an 80% chance of being picked:

```js
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const fruits = [
{name: "Banana"}, 
{name: "Apple"}, 
{name: "Peach"}
]

const car = [
{name: "Audi"}, 
{name: "Bentley"}
]

const books = [
{name: "Alice in wonderland"}, 
{name: "Deep in the dark"}, 
{name: "Hunting Show"}
]

const tempArray = [];

let groupChoice = getRandomNumber(1, 100);
if (groupChoice > 20) {
  tempArray.push(fruits[getRandomNumber(0, fruits.length - 1)].name);
} else {
  tempArray.push(books[getRandomNumber(0, books.length - 1)].name);
}

console.log(tempArray);
```

Comment: np - but bear in mind that this is only for two groups - fruits and books.  If you want to include the car group as well, you will need to update the `if()` tests to allow for other ranges

Answer (score 2):

First we combine the fruits and car arrays. Then we generate a random number from 1 to 100. A number from 1 to 80 would pick a random element from the fruitsAndCar array, and a number from 81 to 100 would pick a random element from the books array.

```
const fruits = [
    {name: "Banana"}, 
    {name: "Apple"}, 
    {name: "Peach"}
]

const car = [
    {name: "Audi"}, 
    {name: "Bentley"}
]

const books = [
    {name: "Alice in wonderland"}, 
    {name: "Deep in the dark"}, 
    {name: "Hunting Show"}
]

const tempArray = []
const fruitsAndCar = fruits.concat(car);

let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1); // 1 to 100

if (randomNumber <= 80) {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitsAndCar.length); // 0 to 4
    tempArray.push(fruitsAndCar[randomIndex]);
} else {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * books.length); // 0 to 2
    tempArray.push(books[randomIndex]);
}

console.log('tempArray: ' + JSON.stringify(tempArray));
```